# Solving differential equation $(f(a)-a)f'(a)=f(a)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To start: I know the solution is
$$
f(a) = a + \sqrt{a^2+2C}
$$
where $C$ is a constant of integration (that can be found with initial conditions).

What I don't know is how to get to this solution from the differential equation.

---

What I have tried: tried to see if It is separable. Doesn't seem to be. That's roughly the extent of my differential equation abilities.

I also tried to see if I could write it LHS is the derivative of something easy (since sometimes I've found that helps), or if I can re-write it in the form where the LHS is the  derivative of something i know. I couldn't figure it out though.

I did notice that
$$
\frac{\partial V(b)b}{\partial b} = V(b) + V'(b)b
$$
which I thought would help. But then I need the integral of $V(b)V'(b)$, which is where I stopped.

Comment: HINT: it is a D'Alembert's equation, try google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Define $f(a)=a+g(a)$ to get $$g(a)\,g'(a)=a\implies \left(g^2(a)\right)'=2a \implies g^2(a)= a^2+C$$

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have one more question: So basically we are "guessing" that $f(a)$ is of the form $a+g(a)$?